# XML comments in MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

Does anyone know how to customize the XML comments in MonoDevelop?  When I add the comments section to a method it automatically generates most of it for me and for the most part I like how it does it, but I would like it to have fewer new lines and thus far I have only found out how to update active code styles.

Comment: No idea, but you can code with Visual Studio :)  I use a shared folder and do 99% of my coding with VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this (other than editing the MonoDevelop source code), but you could file an [enhancement bug](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) with a suggestion of how this could be done.